# ASP.NET: What is the purpose of IAuthorizationService

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-authentication

I am trying to understand the [ASP.NET policy-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0) mechanism, and I understand that I need to do the following:

1. Set up a policy
2. Assign requirements to that policy
3. Define authorization handlers to these requirements which perform the actual validation (And return whether the requirements were fulfilled or not)
4. Add the authorization handlers to the dependency injection mechanism

However, reading the ASP.NET documentation, I understand I might need to set up an IAuthorizationService as well. I failed to understand why that is needed from the ASP.NET documentation.

Do I have to set one up? What should it do? Is that an alternative to the policy and authorization handlers I am setting up or a required addition to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `IAuthorizationService` to take control of full authorization logic in your application.
By default, `IAuthorizationService` is responsible for validation of Policy- Claim- or Role-based ruled, defined in `AuthorizationOptions`.

`IAuthorizationService` is usually being invoked in `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter` (which MVC adds automatically once you mark Controller or Action with `[Authorize]` attribute).